# Checkbox to (un)check all other checkboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I've created a windows form which (so far) contains only checkboxes. The constructor takes one parameter: `string[] attributes`. For each string in this `attributes` array I create a checkbox.

For example:

```
string[] attributes = {
                          "Black",
                          "Red",
                          "Blue"
                      };
form1 = new MyForm(attributes);
form1.Show();
```

Will create checkboxes like so:

```
[ ] Black
[ ] Red
[ ] Blue
```

This works just fine. Now my next step is to create a checkbox "Check All", which has the following behavior. I'll use `this` to refer to my *"Check All" checkbox*.

When:

- User checks `this`: All other checkboxes get checked.
- User unchecks `this`: All other checkboxes get unchecked.
- All other checkboxes get manually checked: `this` gets checked too.
- All checkboxes are checked and any of them gets unchecked: `this` gets unchecked too.

I managed to do all of the above rules but I ran into a problem and I can't figure out how to fix it: When all checkboxes are checked and user unchecks one checkbox, it means that my *"Check All" checkbox* will get unchecked too. Now that my *"Check All" checkbox* got unchecked, it automatically calls for uncheck event which then unchecks ALL of the checkboxes as if the user had unchecked my *"Check All" checkbox*.

So is there a way to tell my checkbox not to run `CheckedChanged` when it's an other checkbox calling the uncheck?

Here's my code (it's all written by hand, so no visual studio designer used):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyForm
{
    public MyForm(string[] attributes)
    {
        SpawnControls(attributes);
    }

    private CheckBox[] m_attributes;
    private CheckBox m_all;

    private void SpawnControls(string[] attributes)
    {
        CheckBox dummy = new CheckBox();
        int nAttr = attributes.Length;

        m_attributes = new CheckBox[nAttr];
        for (int i = 0; i < nAttr; i++)
        {
            m_attributes[i] = new CheckBox();
            m_attributes[i].Text = attributes[i];
            m_attributes[i].Location = new Point(5, dummy.Height * i);
            m_attributes[i].CheckedChanged += attribute_CheckedChanged;
            Controls.Add(m_attributes[i]);
        }

        m_all = new CheckBox();
        m_all.Text = "Check All";
        m_all.Location = new Point(5, m_attributes[nAttr - 1].Bottom);
        m_all.CheckedChanged += all_CheckedChanged;
        Controls.Add(m_all);
    }

    private void attribute_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((CheckBox)sender).Checked)
        {
            foreach (CheckBox cb in m_attributes)
            {
                if (cb.Checked == false)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            m_all.Checked = true;
        }
        else if (m_all.Checked)
        {
            m_all.Checked = false;
        }
    }

    private void all_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_all.Checked)
        {
            foreach (CheckBox cb in m_attributes)
            {
                cb.Checked = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (CheckBox cb in m_attributes)
            {
                cb.Checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check if the All_Check control has focus at the beginning of the event handler, exit  the event if it doesn't have focus.

```
private void all_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!m_all.Focused)
     return ;

    if (m_all.Checked)
    {
        foreach (CheckBox cb in m_attributes)
        {
            cb.Checked = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (CheckBox cb in m_attributes)
        {
            cb.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm an other good solution, I'll take a look at it too, thanks :P

Comment: Ended up using this, is cleaner imo, especially after adding a comment to the if sentence :)

Answer (score 1):

You could either add a boolean member level variable which flags if your event handler logic should short circuit, or you could unsubscribe from `all_CheckedChanged` in `attribute_CheckedChanged` and resubscribe at the end.

Comment: Awesome, didn't think of that. Thanks, I'll accept soon if no other answers are given :)